# ModalPopupExtender only pops up the UpdatePanel once

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The ModalPopupExtender wires the btnCancel button to trigger the a popup an UpdatePanel.  The UpdatePanel is a cancel confirmation which contains a Yes button and a No button.  After clicking the No button, the panel is closed but the btnCancel no longer trigger the popup when being clicked again.  The Yes button works and triggers the server side YesButton_Click event.  Here is my code.  Thanks for your help.

```html
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
  <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel Task" runat="server" ToolTip="Cancel the displayed task and remove it from Tracker" CausesValidation="false" />

  <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnCancel"
    PopupControlID="ConfirmationPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />

  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_yes_no" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="ConfirmationPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
        <div class="modalPopup-text">
          Are you sure you want to cancel this task?<br />
          <br />
          <asp:Button ID="YesButton" runat="server" Text="Yes" CommandArgument="Yes" OnClick="YesButton_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <asp:Button ID="NoButton" runat="server" Text="No" CommandArgument="No" />
        </div>
      </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive but it appears that Extender and Extended controls must reside in the same UpdatePanel. So if you move your Cancel button and ModalPopupExtender control inside the UpdatePanel, it should work as expected.

```
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />

      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_yes_no" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>

    <span id="buttons">
      <asp:Button ID="btnUndo" Text="Undo Edit" CommandArgument="undo" runat="server"
        OnClick="undo" CausesValidation="false" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnNewTask" Text="New Task" CommandArgument="newTask" runat="server"
        ToolTip="Unchange current and create new task"
        OnClick="NewTask" CausesValidation="false" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel Task" runat="server"
        ToolTip="Cancel the displayed task and remove it from Tracker" CausesValidation="false" />
    </span>

    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnCancel" PopupControlID="ConfirmationPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
    <asp:Panel ID="ConfirmationPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
      <div class="modalPopup-text">
        Are you sure you want to cancel this task?
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="YesButton" runat="server" Text="Yes" CommandArgument="Yes" OnClick="YesButton_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="NoButton" runat="server" Text="No" CommandArgument="No" />
      </div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. A minor problem is that the btnCancel is with two other buttons within a SPAN tag as a group.  Moving this button inside the Update Panel cause it to be on its own line.  It is not visually appealing.  I tried moved the SPAN tag and buttons inside the Update Panel.  It caused 500 error complaining the SPAN tag is not allowed.

Comment: Can you provide me the code for the SPAN tag with the buttons that you are trying to put inside the update panel?

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the post with the source code.  The SPAN is styled with #buttons {
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: @user266909 - I updated my answer. I was able to render with <span> tags inside the update panel just fine.